# dropbox file type statistics

Tags: dropbox, statistics

Is there any way to see the percentage of the filtetypes shared on dropbox? I mean, how many music files, how many zip files, how many rar files etc.

Both the figures themselves and percentages would be great.

I hope it's not too much to ask for,

Thank you

Comment: Shared as in public, with other users, or all files on your Dropbox account?

Comment: overall usage statistics. Not necessarily in the public folder but it could be a great start.

Comment: on which OS do you run dropbox. there may be OS-related tools that can do the job for you.

Comment: I am running on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the command line, go to your Dropbox folder, then type the following command:

```
find . -name "*.*" | gawk -F. '(NF>1) {exts[$NF]++} END {for (ext in exts){printf "%s: %s files\n", ext, exts[ext]}}'
```

It will show the number of files for each extension, for instance:

```
mp3: 243 files
txt: 832 files
rar: 9 files
[...]
```

If you are on Windows, you might have to install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) to be able to run this command.

To convert to percentages, use a spreadsheet program like OpenOffice Calc.

Comment: I believe that if you're going to use gawk, its included in [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) and [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) , should there be a need for simpler lighter standalone alternatives to cygwin